# How to open a python file containing kivy code inside another file containing kivy code

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to ask that is it possible to run a python file containing kivy code inside another python file containing kivy code. Like you would do for functions in another python file. If it is possible, how do I do it because kivy contains classes, build function and the `run()` method.

For example if you have two python file called
`a.py` and `b.py`, how do you run code in `a.py` inside `b.py` in kivy. Note don't use `.kv`.

Comment: Did you try just doing it as you would normally for ordinary Python code? Did something go wrong? Can you show an example of something that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Have you tried [import](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)?

Comment: I have tried import but I don't know how to use it in kivy because of the multiple class with widget and build methods it contains, you know the kivy code start with multiple class